# Как пропустить строку if __name__ == '__main__':?

Tags: python

Пользуюсь IDE PyCharm.

Я не хочу включать эту строку, потому что за ней требуется отступ, у меня их и так многовато, что сказывается на читабельности кода.
Мой код:

```
import pyscreenshot as py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    coordinates = [0,0,20,20]
    a=py.grab(bbox=coordinates)
    a.show()
```

Без этой строки ошибка:

```
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Тут сказано, что freeze support() может быть пропущено, но как это сделать?

Comment: "у меня их и так много" — разбивайте ваш код на отдельные функции/классы, чтобы не было слишком много отступов (уменьшить [cyclomatic complexity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цикломатическая_сложность))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на *nix запускаете

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyscreenshot as py

coordinates = [0,0,20,20]
a=py.grab(bbox=coordinates)
a.show()
# end of script
```

Или как по класике

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyscreenshot as py

def main():
    coordinates = [0,0,200,20]
    a=py.grab(bbox=coordinates)
    a.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# end of script
```